# How do I find an element of an array in NiFi ExecuteScript (ECMAScript)?

Tags: javascript, json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a need to get data out of a NiFi flow file with somewhat complex JSON content. I'm planning to use a NiFi `ExecuteScript` processor because I don't think it can be done with `EvaluateJSONPath`. The content looks like this (snippet)

```json
...
  "segments": [
    {
      "INS01": "Y",
      "INS03": "001",
      "INS02": "18",
      "INS05": "A",
      "id": "INS",
      "INS04": "AI",
      "INS08": "FT"
    },
    {
      "REF02": "1041558xxxxx",
      "REF01": "0F",
      "id": "REF"
    },
    {
      "REF02": "ABD",
      "REF01": "1L",
      "id": "REF"
    },
    {
      "REF02": "106835xxxxx",
      "REF01": "23",
      "id": "REF"
    }
  ],
...
```

I want to extract the `REF02` property value from the segments array element that has `REF01 === '0F'`. The array element does not necessarily have a `REF02` property. So in the above case, I should get `1041558xxxxx`.

Here's my current script:

```java
var flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile != null) {
    var InputStreamCallback = Java.type('org.apache.nifi.processor.io.InputStreamCallback')
    var IOUtils = Java.type('org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils')
    var StandardCharsets = Java.type('java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets')
    try {
        var subscriber = null
        session.read(flowFile,
            new InputStreamCallback(function (inputStream) {
                var data = JSON.parse(IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                var segment = data.segments.find(function (s) { return s.hasOwnProperty('REF01') && s.REF01 === '0F' })
                subscriber = segment ? segment.REF02 : null
            }));
        session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'subscriber', subscriber ? subscriber : '')
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    } catch (e) {
        log.error('script failed', e)
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
    }
}
```

When I execute the above, I get a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`. Also, are anonymous 'arrow' functions allow?

I've tried using an old-school `for` loop to no avail.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it's very important the context of `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`. usually this error is saying method name, parameters, on which object, and potentially suggesting solution. does the `groovy` lang is acceptable for you? should be simpler as soon as nifi is java-based platform.

Comment: @daggett Thanks for the info. I fine giving Groovy a shot.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a ***JoltTransformJSON*** processor with specification

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "segments": {
        "*": {
          "REF01": {
            "0F": {// conditional to match "REF01" with "0F" 
              "@2,REF02": ""// go two levels up the three to reach the level of the attributes REF01 or REF02   
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

in order to return the result

```json
"1041558xxxxx"
```

Comment: I want to keep the existing content. I'm guessing there's no way to send the Jolt output straight to an attribute. Instead I'd have to use `UpdateAttribute` and also correlate the original flow file with this one with the new content.

Answer (score 1):

**Groovy script**:

```java
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 

flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def subscriber = ""

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
  input = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
  json = jsonSlurper.parseText(input)
  segment = json.segments.find{ segment -> 
    if (segment.keySet().contains('REF01')) { 
      if (segment.REF01 == '0F') { 
        return true 
      } else { 
        return false
      } 
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
  if (segment) {
    subscriber = segment.REF02
  }
  outputStream.write(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
} as StreamCallback)

session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'subscriber', subscriber)
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

**input**:

```json
{
  "test": "best",
  "segments": [
    {
      "INS01": "Y",
      "INS03": "001",
      "INS02": "18",
      "INS05": "A",
      "id": "INS",
      "INS04": "AI",
      "INS08": "FT"
    },
    {
      "REF02": "1041558xxxxx",
      "REF01": "0F",
      "id": "REF"
    },
    {
      "REF02": "ABD",
      "REF01": "1L",
      "id": "REF"
    },
    {
      "REF02": "106835xxxxx",
      "REF01": "23",
      "id": "REF"
    }
  ]
}
```

**output** (with attribute `subscriber`: `1041558xxxxx`):

```json
{
  "test": "best",
  "segments": [
    {
      "INS01": "Y",
      "INS03": "001",
      "INS02": "18",
      "INS05": "A",
      "id": "INS",
      "INS04": "AI",
      "INS08": "FT"
    },
    {
      "REF02": "1041558xxxxx",
      "REF01": "0F",
      "id": "REF"
    },
    {
      "REF02": "ABD",
      "REF01": "1L",
      "id": "REF"
    },
    {
      "REF02": "106835xxxxx",
      "REF01": "23",
      "id": "REF"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below **`JSONPath`** with **EvaluateJSONPath** processor:

```
$.segments[?(@.REF01<="0F")]@.REF02
```

**Note:** Returned result is in the `array`, So you can use **SplitJSON** after that to get your string.

Comment: @AbhaiRajLlewellyn It's `JSONPath` syntax and `Nifi` uses it. You can write your own `JSONPath` with this website: https://jsonpath.com

Comment: Thx @MohammadReza. I tried using it a `NiFi`. First time, I got an error because it wasn't returning a scalar value. When I changed the `NiFi` `EvaluateJsonPath` processor `Return Type` property to `json`, the path returned an empty array. The path works as expected on [jsonpath.com](https://jsonpath.com/)

Comment: @AbhaiRajLlewellyn I also check it in the nifi and it worked.